# Using an interface as an "out" parameter in C#

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism, abstract-class

How can I use an interface or abstract class as an "out" parameter in a method in another interface? Shouldn't I be able to use an interface as an out parameter in another interface, and then have it accept any class that implements that interface when I actually call the method?

I need a Transaction interface that has a method that returns a bool and populates a "Response" object, but that response object is a different derived object for every different implementation of the Transaction interface. Thanks in advance.

```
namespace csharpsandbox
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TransactionDerived t = new TransactionDerived();
        t.Execute();
    }
}


public interface ITransaction
{
    bool Validate(out IResponse theResponse);
}

public interface IResponse { }



public class ResponseDerived : IResponse
{
    public string message { get; set; }

}

public class TransactionDerived : ITransaction
{
    public bool Validate(out IResponse theResponse) {

        theResponse = new ResponseDerived();
        theResponse.message = "My message";
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        ResponseDerived myResponse = new ResponseDerived();

        if (Validate(out myResponse))
            Console.WriteLine(myResponse.message);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current implementation will work as long as you cast things appropriately:

```
public class TransactionDerived : ITransaction
{
    public bool Validate(out IResponse theResponse)
    {    
        theResponse = new ResponseDerived();
        ((ResponseDerived)theResponse).message = "My message";

        return true;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        IResponse myResponse;

        if (Validate(out myResponse))
            Console.WriteLine(((ResponseDerived)myResponse).message);
    }
}
```

This is messy, however. You can avoid the casting by using a generic interface instead:

```
public interface ITransaction<T> where T : IResponse
{
    bool Validate(out T theResponse);
}

public class TransactionDerived : ITransaction<ResponseDerived>
{
    public bool Validate(out ResponseDerived theResponse)
    {    
        theResponse = new ResponseDerived();
        theResponse.message = "My message";

        return true;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        ResponseDerived myResponse;

        if (Validate(out myResponse))
            Console.WriteLine(myResponse.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution, will test and make sure it does what I need shortly, thank you!

Comment: I just realized this won't quite work because each Transaction implementation can actually have multiple unique Responses... Would my best bet be to cast then?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the system, casting (using the `as` operator will probably be a little cleaner) sounds like the easiest thing to do. Be careful though, if you find yourself needing to inspect types and cast things a lot, it generally indicates a larger problem in your design.

Answer (score 1):

The empty interface definition is pointless (See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182128%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).  Instead, try something like this:

```
public interface ITransaction
{
    bool Validate(out object theResponse);
}
```

and then cast your object appropriately.

Comment: Using this means the consumer of the interface has no contract for the output parameter. How would they know what to expect?

Comment: By the implementation of the interface.  If the interface is of type x, the response is of type y.  You'll need to derive that somewhere anyway, since you have to divine the IResponse implementation to call any of its methods or properties.

Comment: Not the DV, but I assume that this is simplified for the sake of example, and the real `IResponse` interface is non-empty. In any case, this doesn't really explain to the OP how to resolve their issues; "cast your object appropriately" is one solution (the wrong one, I think) but you should give an example, since the OP obviously doesn't know what the appropriate cast is. :)

Comment: @verdesmarald, OP doesn't know what form the response will look like at all, that's why he's trying to use an empty interface to box the response object.  This is what boxing is for; at some point, he will need to use reflection on the IResponse in order to use it at all.  An interface is not the appropriate mechanism here.  (see the link in my answer);

Comment: I disagree, the question says: *"response object is a different derived object for every different implementation of the Transaction interface"* I interpret this to mean that each `ITransaction` implementation always returns the same type of `IResponse`, so a generic `ITransaction` interface is the way to go and reflection is unnecessary.

Comment: OK rereading your response I understand what you're getting at, but I think everyone is missing the point of an interface declaration.  I think your assumption that the `IResponse` interface is not meant to be empty is incorrect.

Comment: Again, I assume that this is a simplified example. Presumably the real system actually has multiple implementations of `ITransaction`, each of which have a corresponding implementation of `IResponse`, and `IResponse` is non-empty. I agree with you that if there really is only one `ITransaction` implementation (and not likely to add others) that this is overkill and it can all just be replaced with concrete classes. This is all irrelevant to the actual question though, which is effectively "how do I pass/use an `out` parameter of a more derived type than the declared parameter?".

Comment: Also, yes I agree with you that empty interfaces are bad design. :)

Comment: @verdesmarald Well, I expect OP asked the wrong question, given this context.  I'll bet the `IResponse` interface is meant to be empty.  Oh well.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! Verdesmarald is correct, there are a ton of ITransaction implementations and each one of those has a unique IResponse implementation. In thinking about it, IResponse might be better suited to be an abstract class rather than an interface, but I run into the same issues either way. IResponse will contain some shared stuff that all implementations have, it is just empty for the sake of simplifying the example.

Comment: In that case, VerdesMarald's implementation is the right way to go.